# this.transform.position + new Vector3(0,y,0) changes the z axis of the game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am instantiating a particular prefab after every 1 second interval.

```
float y = Random.Range(-0.5f, 1f);
GameObject newObject = Instantiate (this.prefabToSpawn, this.transform.position + new Vector3(0,y,0),Quaternion.identity);
```

Every time I instantiate, I just want to change position of the game object along the y - axis , but if I add the above snippet , the new game object goes much behind along the z - axis (even there is a random change in y-axis too though, which seems to be working fine, it just needs to retain its z position), hence wont be visible in the scene anymore. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your new `Vector3` to `this.transform.position`. The problem is that `this.transform.position` will change your x, y and z-axis. If you don't want this to happen, you have to create a temporary `Vector3` variable that you will store the result of `transform.position + new Vector3(0, y, 0);` then you just modify the `Z` axis and set it to `0` or the value you want it to retain.

```
float YOUR_DEFAULT_Z = 0f;
float y = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-0.5f, 1f);
Vector3 tempPos = transform.position + new Vector3(0, y, 0);
//Overide the Z axis 
tempPos.z = YOUR_DEFAULT_Z;

GameObject newObject = Instantiate(prefabToSpawn, tempPos, Quaternion.identity);
```